# How to Insert an ArrayList into Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, derby

I am creating an arraylist from my derby database like this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> createArray(String ticket, JLabel message){


String sl = ticket;
List rowData ;
List<String> columnHeaders;
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tableData =  null;

try{
conn= new data.connection().db();
String query="SELECT * FROM SERVICE_TICKET WHERE TICKET_NO ='"+sl+"' ";
stmtt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);
md = rs.getMetaData();
            int count = md.getColumnCount();
            columnHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
            tableData = new ArrayList<>();
         /*
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                columnHeaders.add(md.getColumnName(i));
                System.out.print(columnHeaders);
            }

         */
            while (rs.next()) {
                rowData = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
                    rowData.add(rs.getObject(i));
                    message.setText(rs.getObject(i).toString());
                }
                tableData.add((ArrayList<String>) rowData);
            }
            System.out.println(tableData);
 }
catch (SQLException ex) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Error!! Data cannot be displayed!"+ex);
} 
finally{try{stmtt.close(); conn.close(); rs.close();} catch(SQLException ex){}}

return tableData;
    }
```

and trying to insert the data into a remote MySQL Database like this:

```
public void save(String ticket, JLabel message){

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tableData = createArray(ticket, message);


 String query = "INSERT INTO SERVICE_TICKET(ID, TICKET_NO, " // VARCHAR(40),
    +" SL_NO, " //INTEGER,
    +" CODE, " // VARCHAR(30),
    +" ITEM_NAME, " // VARCHAR(300),
    +" GROUP_NAME, " // VARCHAR(50),

    +" QNTY, " // INTEGER,
    +" UNIT, " // VARCHAR(30),
    +" TAXABLE, " //  VARCHAR(3),
    +" BONUSABLE, " //  VARCHAR(3),

    +" PRICE, " // DECIMAL(30 , 2),
    +" AMOUNT, "// DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

    +" DISC_PERCENTAGE, " // DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    +" DISCOUNT, " // DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

    +" FEDERAL, " //  DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    +" GST, " // DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    +" TOTAL_TAX, " // DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

    +" NET_AMOUNT) " // DECIMAL(30 , 2) 
        +" VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ;


 try{
     Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://www.example.com:3306/myDatabase", "user_1", "password_123");
     conn.setAutoCommit(false);
     stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
 if(conn != null ){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to Internet....");}
 else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to connect to the server");}


     for(int i = 0; i<tableData.size(); i++){ 
     ArrayList<String> innerList = (ArrayList<String>)tableData.get(i);
     for(int j = 0; j<innerList.size(); j++){ 

     stmt.setString(1, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //   TICKET_NO VARCHAR(40),
     stmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //SL_NO INTEGER,
     stmt.setString(3, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //CODE VARCHAR(30),
     stmt.setString(4, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(300),
     stmt.setString(5, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; // GROUP_NAME VARCHAR(50),

     stmt.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; // QNTY INTEGER,
     stmt.setString(7, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //    UNIT VARCHAR(30),
     stmt.setString(8, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //    TAXABLE VARCHAR(3),
     stmt.setString(9, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //    BONUSABLE VARCHAR(3),

     stmt.setDouble(10, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   PRICE DECIMAL(30 , 2),
     stmt.setDouble(11, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   AMOUNT DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

     stmt.setDouble(12, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   DISC_PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
     stmt.setDouble(13, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   DISCOUNT DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

     stmt.setDouble(14, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   FEDERAL DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
     stmt.setDouble(15, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   GST DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
     stmt.setDouble(16, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   TOTAL_TAX DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

     stmt.setDouble(17, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   NET_AMOUNT DECIMAL(30 , 2)

     stmt.addBatch(); 

     stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();

 }}

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved successfully.");
 }
 catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot Save"+ex);}
 finally{
 try{
     stmt.close(); conn.close(); conn.setAutoCommit(true);
 }catch(SQLException ex){}
 }
 }
```

The arraylist displays fine in console. But it gives me always NumberFormatException...
What is wrong in my code ?

One more Question: Is there any other option, that I can insert my table data from local computer (Running in Derby Database) to a remote MySQL database ?
Please help.

Comment: Would it be overkill for your application if you were to use JPA so you don't need to write all the data layer code manually? If so, I could dig up an example how to do this with Derby.

Comment: I just need a solution. But what's wrong with arraylist and my code?

Comment: May be while inserting data from derby to MySQL you are doing some wrong conversion. You are trying to insert a string into a numeric field. Check your numeric value in derby, that may be containing some char or string

Comment: @Pranjal - I wasn't implying something is wrong with using the tools you're currently using, especially if the project is very small. I was just curious so I could provide an answer using JPA if it is acceptable. And I'm also pointing out that one of the reasons to use JPA is because it significantly reduces, if not eliminates, bugs from manually writing JDBC code. It also simplifies the application and allows you to focus more on your business logic. It also allows you to do what you're trying to do, switch DB vendors, very easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you're wrong:

```
for(int j = 0; j<innerList.size(); j++){ 

stmt.setString(1, innerList.get(j).toString()) ; //   TICKET_NO VARCHAR(40),
stmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //SL_NO INTEGER,
```

Observe that you're always accessing the same index from the `innerList`: `j`. When in fact you probably want something more along the lines of

```
for (int j = 0; j < innerList.size(); j++) { 
    stmt.setObject(j + 1, innerList.get(j));
}
```

Besides, [Siva Mondi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596288/521799) also has a correct observation with `executeBatch()` and `commit()` being at the wrong loop level. Intuitively, I'd say there are about 1-2 other problems in that code... As mentioned in the comments, you might indeed be better off with a higher abstraction level, such as [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), [Spring JDBC](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/) or [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)

Comment: As I said. You always access the same index `j` from your `innerList` for each column, when in fact `innerList` contains one value per column.

Comment: Anyway, How to get rid of it ?

Comment: The second `for` of Lukas is the hint! You already have the counter 'j' then use it!

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara: You *will* have to do some of the thinking and some of the work yourself, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1):

Please carefully check these lines again:

```
 stmt.setDouble(10, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   PRICE DECIMAL(30 , 2),
 stmt.setDouble(11, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   AMOUNT DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

 stmt.setDouble(12, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   DISC_PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
 stmt.setDouble(13, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   DISCOUNT DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

 stmt.setDouble(14, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   FEDERAL DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
 stmt.setDouble(15, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   GST DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
 stmt.setDouble(16, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //   TOTAL_TAX DECIMAL(30, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,

 stmt.setDouble(17, Double.parseDouble(innerList.get(j).toString())) ; //
```

You're trying to parse a string to a double value. But the string is not double type that lead to NumberFormatException. For example:

```
Double a = Double.parseDouble("asd"); //java.lang.NumberFormatException occurs
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your for loop. You should take out 
    stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit(); and keep out side of the for loop

Comment: True, that's another bug, although not the one causing the observed `NumberFormatException`...

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? The erroneous code is quite a mess and Siva just tried to help, spotting another problem that would have led to yet another question...